# How can I add the cypress-plugin-tab to the cypress.config,js

Tags: automation, cypress

I am struggling to add the tab plugin to the cypress.config.js.
As of Cypress version 10.0.0, you will need to add your plugin to the setupNodeEvents function in the Cypress configuration and before that, they were in the index.js file.

This is the documentation for the tab plugin - https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-plugin-tab .
I can't figure out how to add it to the config file. The documentation suggests I add it to the index file but it is 3 years old

It suggests I add

```
require('cypress-plugin-tab')
```

to the index file but doesn't work with the new cypress

Answer (score 1):

Although the package is named `cypress-plugin-tab`, it's not a plugin in that goes in the `setupNodeEvents` of `cypress.config.js`.

It's just a custom command, see [cypress-plugin-tab/src/index.js](https://github.com/kuceb/cypress-plugin-tab/blob/61db462718cdc791194d577555cc88f58c176996/src/index.js#L5)

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('tab', { prevSubject: ['optional', 'element'] }, 
  (subject, opts = {}) => {...
```

Just import it into the `support/e2e.js` file, or even at the top of your test.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `cypress/support/e2e.js` and then add `require('cypress-plugin-tab')`. This should work.